# Extension that makes wrapper that dispenses self typed as self

Tags: ios, swift, generics

Sorry for the weird title. Here's a toy sketch of my code:

```
extension UIControl {
    func makeHolder() -> ControlHolder {
        ControlHolder(control: self)
    }
}

struct ControlHolder {
    let control : UIControl
    init(control: UIControl) {
        self.control = control
    }
    func retrieve() -> UIControl {
        return self.control
    }
}
```

I admit this is a toy reduction, and I don't like when people do that, but it illustrates the syntactical issue perfectly, so let's go with it.

Okay, so we have an extension on UIControl that is a method that returns a wrapper object. Now, the problem is this:

```
let holder = UISwitch().makeHolder()
let output = holder.retrieve()
```

The result, `output`, is typed as UIControl, obviously. But that isn't what I want. I want it to be typed as UISwitch, because I started with a UISwitch. OK, so that sounds like a generic. The problem is, I can't figure out how to make that generic.

It's easy, I think, to make ControlHolder a generic:

```
struct ControlHolder<T:UIControl> {
    let control : T
    init(control: T) {
        self.control = control
    }
    func retrieve() -> T {
        return self.control
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure I've got that part right. But then how do I write the extension declaration in such a way as to resolve that generic to the actual type of `self`, the UIControl on which `makeHolder` is called?

I tried introducing a generic to the extension, obeying the compiler until I got it to compile:

```
extension UIControl {
    func makeHolder<T>() -> ControlHolder<T> {
        ControlHolder<T>(control: self as! T)
    }
}
```

But that's pretty silly, and `output` is still typed as UIControl.

Obviously I can add another parameter passing the type explicitly into `makeHolder` and thus resolving it:

```
extension UIControl {
    func makeHolder<T>(ofType: T.Type) -> ControlHolder<T> {
        ControlHolder<T>(control: self as! T)
    }
}
```

Now when I call `makeHolder` I pass in the type:

```
let holder = UISwitch().makeHolder(ofType: UISwitch.self)
let output = holder.retrieve()
```

And now of course `output` is typed as UISwitch. But this is idiotic! I want the extension to just *know* that the type is UISwitch, because I'm calling `makeHolder` on a UISwitch.

I feel like I'm coming at this all wrong. Maybe someone can straighten me out? Or am I aiming for something that's just impossible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick to this is to define a protocol, an extension of that protocol, and put the `makeHolder` method in that extension. That way, you can use `Self` as the generic type for the returned `ControlHolder`.

First define a new protocol (let's call it "`HoldableControl`") and require that conformers must be `UIControl`s. It doesn't need any other requirements because we just care about adding the `makeHolder` function to an extension.

```swift
protocol HoldableControl: UIControl {}
```

Then, add an extension of `HoldableControl` and define `makeHolder` in it, returning `ControlHolder<Self>`. We are allowed to use `Self` here because it is allowed in protocol extensions, unlike in an extension to `UIControl`.

```swift
extension HoldableControl {
    func makeHolder() -> ControlHolder<Self> {
        ControlHolder(control: self)
    }
}
```

Then, we just need to have `UIControl` conform to this protocol:

```swift
extension UIControl: HoldableControl {}
```

And make your `ControlHolder` generic, as you've already done:

```swift
struct ControlHolder<T: UIControl> {
    let control: T
    
    init(control: T) {
        self.control = control
    }
    
    func retrieve() -> T {
        control
    }
}
```

And now it will work:

```swift
let holder = UISwitch().makeHolder() // type is ControlHolder<UISwitch>
let output = holder.retrieve()       // type is UISwitch
```

Comment: "define a protocol, an extension of that protocol, and put the makeHolder method in that extension. That way, you can use Self as the generic type for the returned ControlHolder." I feared it would be something along those lines! :)

Comment: Yeah it's a weird roundabout way of solving the problem and I hate it, lol. I wish we could just use `Self` in a class's extension, but it only works in a protocol's extension for some reason. ‍♂️

Comment: Your solution works perfectly (as you know). Thanks for taking the problem seriously! These sorts of thing always make my eyes glaze over...

Comment: This solution has transformed my existence. The _real_ use case is a general Combine framework Publisher on a UIControl.

Comment: Awesome! Can't wait to see the real use case on https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/toc.html (which is what I'm assuming you're updating, haha) :)

Comment: Correct, I'm fixing up this page now: https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/publishers/publisherscustom.html I'm adding (1) the ability to specify the control event and (2) the generic implementation you just provided.